# How to store an attribute in the Selenium IDE from the parent element of child to variable

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide, attributes

I need to storeAttribute "**//images.wbstatic.net/promotions/wide/51597.jpg**" to variable by child "**span class="countdown-hours**""
Can anyone help?

```
<img alt="Autumn Sale" src="//images.wbstatic.net/promotions/wide/51597.jpg">
<div class="countdown-container" data-end-time="\/Date(1444856400000+0300)\/" data-start-time="\/Date(1444805633216+0300)\/">
to the end is
<div class="countdown-timer">
    <span class="countdown-days">
        <span class="dots">:</span>
        <span class="countdown-hours">
            07
        <span>hours</span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the follwoing XPath to get the `img` tag.

```
//div[@class='countdown-container'][.//span[@class = 'countdown-hours']]//preceding-sibling::img
```

The xpath finds the `div` tag next to the `img` tag which contains `span` with class `count-hours` and moves back to the `img` tag.

Comment: Yeah!!! It`s work! But you forgot the "@src" element at the end for the **storeAttribute** command.
Thanks man!